# C: Copying Pointer data using = (Equal to)

Tags: c, pointers

This is my first post here. I tried to find a similar question but couldn't find any and hence I am posting this question.

I am trying to copy the data in a structure pointer to another structure pointer in C as shown below. Looks like using just an '=' did the trick. Could someone please explain how the data in pointer srcStruct got copied to another memory location (pointer by destStruct) without using memcpy()?

Is this a pointer property? or is there any risk in doing this?

```
struct myTestStruct
{
    short variable1;
    short variable2;
};
struct myTestStruct *destStruct = (struct myTestStruct *)malloc(sizeof(struct myTestStruct));
struct myTestStruct *srcStruct = (struct myTestStruct *)malloc(sizeof(struct myTestStruct));
srcStruct->variable1 = 11;
srcStruct->variable2 = 12;
*destStruct = *srcStruct;
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
AJK

Answer (score 1):

By using the dereferencing operator `*`, you are basically treating the data that the pointers point to as regular variables. Structs are copied by value, not by reference, if you aren't copying the pointer, so it's just like copying an int to another int. You are essentially doing the following by using the dereference operator `*`:

```
struct myTestStruct destStruct, srcStruct;
srcStruct.variable1 = 11;
destStruct = srcStruct;           //this gets copied by value
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here isn't actually connected to pointers at all; it's a property of structs in general in C that they can be assigned as a whole unit with a single `=` operation. When you dereference a pointer you're using the pointed-to value directly in the expression, so what you've really got there, with a dereference on both sides, is an assignment from a value struct to another value struct. The pointers have both been "expanded out", leaving the values of the whole structs themselves.

How the value is copied is up to the compiler. It will likely emit custom instructions to do it in the most efficient possible way, but it could also use `memcpy` if it wanted to. There is absolutely no risk in doing this - structs being assignable is a core element of the C language and not going away! It is perfectly idiomatic, and usually the best way to do whatever you're doing that needs data copied from one struct to another. Certainly better than invoking `memcpy` unnecessarily.